# Swift/iOS13 - Access SceneDelegate window variable in a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

Is it possible to access window variable from SceneDelegate in a ViewController? Basically I need an alternative for this `UIApplication.shared.delegate.window` but can't find anything

Comment: You don't need the scene (or app) delegate to get the window. From a view controller, do `self.view.window`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Updated

From **iOS 13**, apps can have multiple active windows, so you need to access the window you want. So you can access a window of any `View` like this:

```
self.view.window
```

if you *really* want to access the `UISceneDelegate` you can access it like:

```
self.view.window.windowScene.delegate
```

## Old: and NOT recommended:

**Assuming**

1. there is only one scene delegate.
2. There is only one scene and one window.
3. All view controllers in the app are all part of that one scene and its window.

You can implement a helper variable in `SceneDelegate` like this:

```
private(set) static var shared: SceneDelegate?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    Self.shared = self
}
```

then you can access it anywhere like this:

```
SceneDelegate.shared?.window // or anything else
```

Comment: `SceneDelegate.shared?.window` it's cool only if you have only ONE scene which is not natural for scenes 