# Swift/iOS13 - UIApplication.shared.delegate.window?.rootViewController?.present() from custom class

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I created a new **Storyboard project** in Xcode11 and trying to present a ViewController from **custom class** like this(which works just fine in older project):

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as UIViewController
appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Of course this doesn't work now because there is no window variable in AppDelegate anymore which has been moved to the SceneDelegate.

**Error:** `Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'window'`

How would you make this code work now?

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to show a ViewController when user taps/clicks on the Push Notification Tray.

**EDIT:** For now I was able to make it work by creating a private static variable in SceneDelegate, and accessing that variable in my custom class:

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
private(set) static var shared: SceneDelegate?
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    Self.shared = self
}
```

**CustomClass.swift**

```
let sceneDeleage = SceneDelegate.shared
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as UIViewController
sceneDeleage?.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
sceneDeleage?.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Which is probably not recommended as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58547992/9511942, but it works

**EDIT2:** Here is my another solution thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557634/9511942

```
    let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as UIViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = vc
```

If someone finds a better solution, please share.

Comment: Check your app delegate file that is there a `var window: UIWindow?` or not

Comment: It's not there since new xcode11 projects come with windows variable in scenedelegate. If I add it in appdelegate, my code just does nothing since it's nil and I get `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` if I force unwrap `window!`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIApplication.shared.delegate equivalent for SceneDelegate xcode11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588843/uiapplication-shared-delegate-equivalent-for-scenedelegate-xcode11)

Comment: It's actually not a duplicate, I just didn't want to ask 2 questions in 1. The answer from there works in ViewController just fine. But I can't implement it in a custom class.

Comment: Use the UIApplication.shared.windows property for getting the Application Windows.  Please refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623104-windows

Answer (score 2):

Use the `UIApplication.shared.windows` property for getting the Application Windows.  Please refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623104-windows

Comment: How does using `UIApplication.shared.windows` solve the issue? An app can have multiple scenes. How would the custom class know which window is the proper window simply by iterating the application windows?