# How to change theme style (User Interface Style) immediately in Swift in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios-darkmode

I'm using Swift 5.1 and Xcode 11.1 and I've currently finished implementing **Dark Mode** design.

App has setting where user can set display theme(**Light**, **Dark**, **System Default**) and currently it's working fine if app restarts after user selects theme(I save this bool data in UserDefaults and set UIAppearance at app startup in AppDelegate file)

Here's my code

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   switch AppState.appThemeStyle {
   case "dark":
       window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
       break
   case "light":
       window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
       break
   default:
       window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .unspecified
   }
}
```

But I can see that many apps change display themes immediately after user sets theme style.

I think It's not good idea to restart app for only changing theme and theme should change immediately after user sets theme style.

I tried to do that by setting base viewcontroller and set user interface style on ViewWillAppear but Navigation bar & Tab bar appearance doesn't change.

Could anyone please tell me how to handle this?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `self` instead of window ? And triggering a notification could help too

Comment: As I mentioned in question, this code is for appdelegate.

Comment: And I'm asking if you tried to do it in each of your VC, by registering/triggering a notification when the user changes the setting ?

Comment: I already tried that. The problem is that navigatino bar & tab bar appearance doesn't change as I mentioned in question.

Comment: This code is instant and there is no need to restart the app! I think you use this code in a wrong way.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini As I mentioned, I implemented this code in AppDelegate file, How come this code can be executed when user change display setting ?

Comment: Oh, @MojtabaHosseini You are right. Thanks

Comment: @MobileStar If some view is not changing automatically, you need to check if you use a dynamic `UIColor` and if not possible, react to `traitCollectionDidChange` to adapt the colors to the new environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code is instant and there is no need to restart the app!

You just need to call the code on user interaction with **notification observer** pattern or directly call the function.

But the point is to access the visible window and `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` there. So for example you can set it from any visible `view` like:

```
view.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

#### Deprecated but working method

```
// Because you are using AppDelegate for this: (But it is going to be deprecated. read the following Note)
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).myFunctionThatChangesTheUserInterfaceStyle()
```

Also **note that** since iOS 13, the key window is not a part of appDelegate anymore and you should [access it from sceneDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547907/swift-ios13-access-scenedelegate-window-variable-in-a-viewcontroller/58547992#58547992)

Comment: You are right and I upvoted your answer, but I think you need to use guard let , or if let when accessing Appdelegate.

Comment: Force unwrap is perfectly fine here because no one can be app delegate instead of `AppDelegate`

Comment: I agree, But one more question, how can I change status bar text color depends on theme change?

Comment: That is `viewController` based. Please feel free to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and comment the link to it here. So I can help you with more description.

Comment: Here it is. Could you please check and help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58589634/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-immediately-in-swift-in-ios-13

Answer (score 1):

We can change user interface style immediately by setting overrideUserInterfaceStyle.
I added this code where user can select theme style.

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
   return
}
appDelegate.changeTheme(themeVal)
```

I hope this will help others