# How to change status bar text color immediately in Swift in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios-darkmode

I'm using Swift 5.1 and Xcode 11.1 and I've currently finished implementing Dark Mode design.

Theme updates immediately after user changes theme style in settings page with this code.

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
   return
}
appDelegate.changeTheme(themeVal)

// App Delegate File
...
func changeTheme(themeVal: String) {
   if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
       switch AppState.appThemeStyle {
       case "dark":
           window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
           break
       case "light":
           window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
           break
       default:
           window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .unspecified
       }
   }
}
```

But the problem is that I can't see status bar text because status bar text color and view color is same.

Could anyone please suggest me good solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Status bar color is not global (by default) and if you set that to not `ViewControllerBased`, you can't change it anymore. So you need to change set it inside any view you need like this:

```
var statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default { didSet { setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() } }
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { statusBarStyle }
```

these two variables help you to change the status bar. Note that you can call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` inside an animation block to make it animatable.

to detect when `UserInterfaceStyle` change (and update statusBar color accordingly), all views and viewControllers have delegate function for that. So knowing that:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
        updateStatusBarColor()
    }
}
```

And this is *the function*:

```
func updateStatusBarColor() {
    switch traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
    case .unspecified: statusBarStyle = .default
    case .light: statusBarStyle = .darkContent
    case .dark: statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    }
}
```

### Note that:

the ParentViewController defines the `statusBarColor`. So if you are using general `navigationController` or `tabBarController`, A custom class for them with these codes should be enough.

Comment: Can you please re-review my question? do we need traitCollectionDidChange function? I think we can do it in changeTheme() func I made? and what contents will be in myFunctionThatUpdatesStatusBar?

Comment: I have added the *function* and the answer is **yes**. Because you want it to be synced with `UserInterfaceStyle` changes. Didn't you?

Comment: I tried with you solution , sorry but it doesn't work.

Comment: How come status bar style value can be returned to setNeedsStatusBarAppearnace ?

Comment: That is not **return**. That is **didSet** property observer.

Comment: This code is instant and tested! I think you use this code in a wrong way. Can you tell me your view hierarchy and where did you put this code ?

Comment: And view hierarchy? Isn't  `BaseViewController` inside a `NavigationController` or `TabBarController`?

Comment: It's inside NavigationController

Comment: So follow the very last line of the answer and put this inside `BaseNavigationController` ;)

Comment: UpdateStatusBarColor got called but statusbar color doesn't change

Comment: I asked for view hierarchy! maybe the navigation controller is inside another controller or something.

Comment: It didn't work because I set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to false in Info.plist. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: No problem. But I have mentioned that in the first line.

Comment: I forgot to check, my bad :(